# Unit testing asynchronous code

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, asynchronous, moq

I have simple class with simple method like this:

```
partial class SimpleClass
{
    private readonly ISimpleManager _simpleManager;
    public SimpleClass(ISimpleManager simpleManager)
    {
        _simpleManager = simpleManager;
    }

    public async void SimpleMethod()
    {
        IsInProgress = true;
        DoSomeWork();
        Task<int> hardWork0Task = _simpleManager.DoHardWork0Async();
        Task<int> hardWork1Task = _simpleManager.DoHardWork1Async();
        DoIndependentWork();
        int hardWork0Result = await hardWork0Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        DoDependentWork(hardWork0Result);
        int hardWork1Result = await hardWork1Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        DoDependentWork(hardWork1Result);
        IsInProgress = false;
    }
}
```

Let's assume that property `IsInProgress` is just `bool` property notifying GUI about its state to allow refreshing progress bar. `DoSomeWork`, `DoDependentWork` and `DoIndependentWork` are some methods using or not results of hard work.

`ISimpleManager` is the most simple interface you can imagine in this case:

```
interface ISimpleManager
{
    Task<int> DoHardWork0Async();
    Task<int> DoHardWork1Async();
}
```

I have to write some unit tests using Moq and NUnit. How can I write unit tests for this case? I would like to check if state of `IsInProgress` property hasn't changed to false during entire code running asynchronously with GUI. Does it make sense? Is it possible? What if my `async` method returns `Task` or generic `Task<T>`? What if I configure awaits for `true`?

Comment: You can make the code run for a very long time using a stub, and then you'll be able to catch the in-progress state.

Comment: Having async method which returns `void` is bad idea. I would suggest to remove `IsInProgress` property and return `Task` instead.

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy, ok, as far as I mentioned, I don't mind using `Task` or generic `Task<T>` instead of `void`. Could you show me in answer complete solution only for `Task` returning method? It would be helpful for me. And I have additional question. If you are developing tests for Caliburn view model, you have some methods that have to be `async void`, i.e. action bound to button click event. What to do in this case? Show publicly method returning `Task` except method returning `async void`? It sounds not so good for me, because you are changing your sut code to be testable.

Comment: @Ilya Kogan, do you mean using sleeping or delaying methods? It's completely not acceptable for me.

Comment: @pt12lol I mean Task.Delay() in the mock. Why isn't it acceptable in a unit test?

Comment: @Ilya Kogan, it was my idea from a long time but my team mates rejected it. Managing it by using locks or something like this would be the best solution, because it would does not delay tests processing time unnecesarily. But you can put your solution in the answer. It might be the best one.

Comment: Why down votes for my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to control when your `ISimpleManager` tasks complete. You can do so with `SemaphoreSlim`, as per Ilya's answer, or you can just use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` directly. I generally prefer `TaskCompletionSource<T>` because it's simpler; however, a `SemaphoreSlim` instance can be reused while a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` can only be triggered once.

On a side note, you should avoid `async void` unless the method is an event handler. It should **not** be a "default" of any kind - the default should be to return `Task` unless you absolutely **can't**. So in this example, `SimpleMethod` should certainly return `Task`.

Here's what it could look like using TCS:

```
async Task MyTestMethod()
{
  // Set up the mock object
  var tcs0 = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
  var tcs1 = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
  var stub = new Mock<ISimpleManager>();
  stub.Setup(x => x.DoHardWork0Async()).Returns(tcs0.Task);
  stub.Setup(x => x.DoHardWork1Async()).Returns(tcs1.Task);

  var sut = new SimpleClass(stub.Object);
  var task = sut.SimpleMethod();

  Assert.True(sut.InProgress);
  tcs0.SetResult(7);
  Assert.True(sut.InProgress);
  tcs1.SetResult(13);
  await task;
  Assert.False(sut.InProgress);
}
```

Comment: Works as expected. Even for `async void` signature (of course excluding keywords `async` and `await` in test).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can unit-test that `IsInProgress` is set correctly:

1. Create an awaitable semaphore:

   ```
   var sem = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
   ```
2. Create a stub `ISimpleManager` with the following implementation:

   ```
   async Task<int> DoHardWork0Async() {
      await sem.WaitAsync();
      return 0;
   }
   ```
3. Call `SimpleMethod`. It will get stuck on the sempahore inside the call to `DoHardWork0Async`
4. Verify the effects of `IsInProgress`
5. As a cleanup step, release the semaphore:

   ```
   sem.Release();
   ```